# Why exactly does this Lucene query return no hits?

Tags: java, lucene, lexical-analysis

There's a bug I filed long ago with Lucene, looking for an answer to this same question. But a lot time has passed and not even the developer of the analyser seems to be willing to answer my questions, so I thought I would throw it out to the floor to see if anyone else can explain what's going on here.

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.ja.JapaneseAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.index.LeafReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.LeafReaderContext;
import org.apache.lucene.index.MultiFields;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Terms;
import org.apache.lucene.index.TermsEnum;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.flexible.standard.StandardQueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.flexible.standard.config.StandardQueryConfigHandler;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.RAMDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef;

public class LuceneMissingTerms {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (Directory directory = new RAMDirectory()) {
            Analyzer analyser = new JapaneseAnalyzer();

            try (IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, new IndexWriterConfig(analyser))) {
                Document document = new Document();
                document.add(new TextField("content", "blah blah commercial blah blah \u79CB\u8449\u539F blah blah", Field.Store.NO));
                writer.addDocument(document);
            }

            try (IndexReader multiReader = DirectoryReader.open(directory)) {
                for (LeafReaderContext leaf : multiReader.leaves()) {
                    LeafReader reader = leaf.reader();

                    Terms terms = MultiFields.getFields(reader).terms("content");
                    TermsEnum termsEnum = terms.iterator();
                    BytesRef text;
                    //noinspection NestedAssignment
                    while ((text = termsEnum.next()) != null) {
                        System.out.println("Term in index: " + text.utf8ToString());
                    }
                }

                StandardQueryParser queryParser = new StandardQueryParser(analyser);
            queryParser.setDefaultOperator(StandardQueryConfigHandler.Operator.AND);
                String queryString = "\"\u79CB\u8449\u539F\"";
                // quoted to work around strange behaviour of StandardQueryParser treating this as a boolean query.
                Query query = queryParser.parse(queryString, "content");
                System.out.println("Performing query: " + queryString);

                TopDocs topDocs = new IndexSearcher(multiReader).search(query, 10);
                System.out.println("Hits count: " + topDocs.totalHits);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you run this, the output is as follows:

```
Term in index: blah
Term in index: commercial
Term in index: 秋葉原
Performing query: "秋葉原"
Hit count: 0
```

So we have a term in the index where the query for exactly that term does not find it. Usually in this happens, you're not using the same analyser when indexing as you are for querying, but in the example above, the same analyser object is used for both.

So I'm assuming there is a bug in the analyser and that it's something to do with the context around the word because that's the only thing that's different in the two situations, but I don't have a clear idea what the actual problem is or how I would work around it.

On the other hand, maybe this is expected behaviour? If that is the case then I can close my ticket as well and the end user will probably just be a bit miffed that we sat on this problem for a couple of years before closing the issue like that.

Comment: Why do you have these extra quotes around the your query string and are not searching with `queryString = "\u79CB\u8449\u539F"`? Does it work if you leave them out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This certainly looks like intended behavior, to me.  I don't really understand the ins and outs of Japanese linguistic analysis at all, but the Kuromoji analyzer has functionality to split out multiple terms, includes a stemmer, and analyzes with part of speech in mind.  A sequence of Japanese characters embedded in a bunch of English text simply doesn't have the same meaning to the analyzer as the terms on their own do, or as they would within Japanese full text.

`StandardAnalyzer` would work just fine for the particular case you present.  If your actual use case is occasional Japanese sequences within English text, the you should probably be using that.  It's meant to handle multiple languages reasonably well.

The kuromoji analyzer appears to work well on *actual* Japanese full text.  I tried indexing some content from the [Akihabara (秋葉原) Japanese Wikipedia page](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%A7%8B%E8%91%89%E5%8E%9F), and it worked quite well, either with or without the quotes in the query.  Language-specific analyzers include a lot of additional intelligence geared specifically toward that language, but in exchange they are not able to handle multiple languages like StandardAnalyzer.

I suspect that is the real problem here, the test case is just a bit too naive.  Your test document is largely English, so `EnglishAnalyzer` or `StandardAnalyzer` would both probably be more appropriate for searching it than `JapaneseAnalyzer`.

Comment: You're right about the Japanese Analyzer generating different terms, the query parser generates a MultiPhraseQuery equivalent to `content:"(秋葉 秋葉原) 原"`. What OP wants is a `new TermQuery(new Term("content", "秋葉原"))` though I don't know how to achieve this with the query parser.

Comment: I guess the one bit that I don't get is why it discards the "秋葉" and "原" terms (wow, I'm submitting this comment multiple times because the SO comment box sucks with IMEs!) but only in one of the two situations. I am sure that it's to do with the context... We do default to StandardAnalyzer and the actual use case is not ours. Other users use our software, we don't have the luxury of being some walled off service who can control the settings of every user. This particular user chose to use the Japanese analysis line and then reported this bug when they discovered it.

Comment: That said, the context is different _somehow_, but when I run sentences vs. individual words through the Kuromoji demo page, the results for that word appear to be the same.